# Avoid double requests to database

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've built an eCommerce solution on Nuxt.js (vue.js and node.js) with a headless cms called Cockpit. I am using a third-party payment gateway that, when payment is valid, redirects the user to a callback url.

On my callback url I have multiple actions going on: Create shipment, Add order to Cockpit and post order data to an invoice software. Also confirmation mails and shipping labels are generated. Labels and mails are sent twice too, and this is annoying for the customer + it costs money to generate the shipping labels. Everything is posting and working as intended.

My issue is, that the payment gateway sometimes call my callback url twice within milliseconds, and therefore creating a duplicate order in Cockpit, since first request haven't finished before the second one is started, and therefore my check for double orders fails, because in theory no order with that transaction id exists yet.

To check for double orders I do the following - this is done as soon as the user hits the callback url:

- I check if the transaction id I get from the payment gateway already
  exists in Cockpit.
- I check if the transaction id exists in the server
  session already.

My question finally is - do you guys have any suggestions to how I can avoid and eliminate those double orders? Maybe some of you tried something like this before?

*I am sorry for the long post, but I feel it's necessary for this to be a valid question on StackOverflow*

Comment: can you check this article http://www.codereadability.com/preventing-a-callback-from-accidentally-being-called-twice/ would be helpful

Comment: @souravlahoti I'm not sure if this would help, since a potential cache Object would be destroyed on the second callback call, since it's a new page request, right? Or do I misunderstand the concept?

Comment: i think @souravlahoti has misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @skolind did you check the second option, it uses a fan that checks for a second call, since it’s bind to this, a second call LL have the same arguments, if I am not wrong

Comment: @souravlahoti I am pretty sure that the page would still be a new one, and completely fresh. Like a page reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is not on your side: the first question is "why the third-party payment gateway call your callback two times ? Does it make 2 payment ?" I think you should try to understand this before anything else, with the help of the payment gateway guys, since this is not normal.

In the meantime, or if you are not be able to solve on the other side, you can try to implement some sort of locking for the current order or a queue for the callback function so that if a second callback for the same order arrive, it can be blocked, discarded or stopped until the first one end (and, at this time, I suppose that the second call will find the order already processed so no more double print and email)

Comment: Thank you. I'm already in dialog with the gateway guys, and they're working on it. I need to find a solution meantime though. I've tried to add the session check but that is not fast enough it seems. What's your idea of a queue?

Comment: @skolind If it is only a temporary solution and depending on what database and table structure you are using, I'd go with getting an exclusive lock on the row(s) needed as first thing and then let the second callback die (with error) or wait. If also this is not fast enough, there are some node.js modules that implement  a proper queue, but probably you need to rewrite much more code, which make no sense in your situation.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment, sorry. The issue for me is, that in my mind, I am thinking that because it's 2 requests to the same page, everything *on* page is reloaded and run twice, so it has to be some server side check. But the server is not fast enough to create a session, so what's really left for me to do?

Comment: True. But you are checking if the first callback has already done some work. In your condition you need to check if the callback itself is executing (or you are already working the order). A nice way is to use Redis, so: the callback is called -> get the order id and call the `GETSET` method of Redis using the order (or nay unique value for that order) as key with a dummy value. If it return null, then continue (and maybe set the TTL on the key), if it return something not null, then exit (you are already working that order). This should be fast enough

Comment: I realized that I never got back to you. Thanks for your time.